# Add class to Wordpress sidebar navigation lists

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

I'm just wondering if there's a way to add a class to any navigation lists for things like sub-pages, categories, archives, meta?

I can't find anywhere in my templates to add a class as I guess it's all autogenerated?

My parent theme (html5blank) has a section of code (below) where this is referenced but I think it targets all lists in the sidebar...

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar'))
{
    // Define Sidebar Widget Area 1
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __('Widget Area 1', 'html5blank'),
        'description' => __('Description for this widget-area...', 'html5blank'),
        'id' => 'widget-area-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    ));

    // Define Sidebar Widget Area 2
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __('Widget Area 2', 'html5blank'),
        'description' => __('Description for this widget-area...', 'html5blank'),
        'id' => 'widget-area-2',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    ));
}
```

I realised I can add a class to a parent div by amending the `before_widget` line to read something like:

```
'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s CUSTOM-CLASS-HERE">',
```

That does add a class but I still thing it'll be added to any and every widget that's added to the sidebar?

Presumably that will mean any widget that contains a `ul` will inherit styles applied to that class, which will break the widget's appearance?

Hope someone can help with this :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add classes to menu items (or to menus) from WP Dashboard.

- Appearance > Menus > Screen Options
- Show Advanced > CSS Classes
- Click any menu item to expand and add classes.

In CSS, you can always prefix those  the classes with a specific `id` or `class` of a widget area, to only apply styles in specific sidebars/widget areas.

if you need to add a class to all your menu items programatically, use the 
`nav_menu_link_attributes` hook:

```
function add_your_menu_classes( $atts, $item, $args ) {
  if( /* condition based on $args or $item (WP_Post object)
       * (in case you only want this when a particular condition
       * is met). If not, just remove the condition */ ) {
    $atts['class'] = 'some-class';
  }
  return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_your_menu_classes', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: To set classes in Appearance, does that mean I need to create new menus for each group of navigation (Pages, Posts, Categories) and add them manually to the templates? Sure you can add a class one a group of pages have been added to a custom menu?

Comment: Your use case is not exactly clear. Note `$item` in the function above holds an object of type `WP_Post` you can check with WP conditionals. You can use it to add custom classes to menu items linking custom posts or posts in specific categories or taxonomies etc...)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I had a feeling I wasn't being very concise! Basically any list of links in the sidebar I want to be able to style. I could do this by targeting `.sidebar-widget ul`, `sidebar-widget li` etc but I was just concerned if I did that, that anything else added to the sidebar would inherit the navigation styling even if it wasn't meant to as the class is too generic and not specific to lists of links?

Comment: Menus have specific selectors. Also, each menu has a specific ID you can use. What you're doing is rarely needed. And the only possible case would be to style links to some type of posts and not others.

Comment: Clearly I need to start using what Wordpress gives me out the box rather than trying to change everything. I'm used to working on custom builds so I can generally markup and use whatever classes I want and dev's will build it accordingly! So I should target `.widget_recent_entries`, `.widget_archive` and `.widget_categories` and apply the same styling to all of them. Is there a way to get child pages to appear in a list in the sidebar already? Or do I need to add something to my functions.php?

Comment: @user1406440 It depends on what widget you are using. There are plugins that define widgets with a lot more options and settings than the default ones. You can always define your own widgets (that's actually what plugins do). You can either place them as plugins (and they'll be theme independent) or inside `functions.php` of your current theme and they'll be theme dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I think if ur widgets, displays a kind of navigation you have to use a custom NavWalker to modify link classes

https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I don't mean if another widget contains navigation. I mean another widget, say a Calendar (random), was marked up using a `ul` the styling would be affected as it would have the same class as the nav lists? Sorry if I'm not making myself clear!